# Поиск по pdf файлам wordpress

Tags: wordpress, поиск, pdf, wordpress-плагины

Есть отдельная страница строительной компании с PDF файлами ( каталогами ) продукции, нужно сделать поиск на данной странице, который будет искать запросы в pdf файлах.

Comment: Не стоит давать  ссылку на внешний сайт. Эта ссылка может измениться или исчезнуть. Здесь же база знаний, пригодная для поиска другими пользователями. Опишите желаемое поведение прямо в вопросе, ссылку на внешний сайт лучше удалить.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, изменил.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен простой вариант поиска по PDF - то это плагин SearchWP с соответствующим аддоном для PDF. Если вариант посложнее - это Elastic Search или Shpinx Search.

В любом случае, для поиска файлы нужно сначала проиндексировать и искать уже по индексу, не распарсивая их при каждом запросе пользователя.